# How to avoid overlap of randomly generated coordinates in a HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to generate a set of text elements inside a triangle  bounded by preset coordinates. For example;
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xdJu.png). Note that the text should be inside the pink triangle. (It is okay if the text clips the triangle's lines since the triangle will be invisible in the final product, this is just for reference)

To achieve this I created the following [codepen.](https://codepen.io/hasala2002/pen/wvqXZYj)

The random generation inside specified boundaries works fine, but since its possible for the same or very close coordinates to be generated, sometimes the text overlaps.

Is there any possible approach I could take to fix/avoid this issue efficiently?

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

function area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
  return Math.abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0);
}

function isInside(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y) {
  let A = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

  let A1 = area(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  let A2 = area(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3);
  let A3 = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y);
  return (A == A1 + A2 + A3);
}

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')

const CANVAS_SIZE = 300

canvas.width = CANVAS_SIZE
canvas.height = CANVAS_SIZE

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let arrayOfText = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
ctx.lineTo(225, 25);
ctx.lineTo(225, 225);
ctx.lineTo(25, 25);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#bb0874"
ctx.stroke()

ctx.font = `600 14px Arial`;

for (let i = 0; i < (arrayOfText.length); i++) {
  while (true) {
    let x = randomIntFromInterval(40, 180)
    let y = randomIntFromInterval(15, 160)
    if (isInside(25, 25, 225, 25, 225, 225, x, y)) {
      ctx.fillText(arrayOfText[i], x, y);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: When adding a new coordinate pair, iterate over previous ones and check the distance. If any fails the distance check, keep generating new coordinates.

Comment: The proposed solution in the comment by @ChrisG is an option, but that is a brute force approach, as you increase the amount of text elements you can run into performance problems, even your current `while (true) {` is not a very efficient way of placing the text, I would recommend you rethink your "random" approach, using a bit more math, you can create predetermined safe areas with padding to avoid overlaps, then within that area you can randomly place your text